# Blazor list not updating after calling functions on it

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a webpage using a video player in blazor web-assembly (.NET 6). This blazor  webpage uses a list of Urls which does not update correctly.

General page logic: The page creates an **IList Videos** of a self-declared class **ExcerciseVideo**. This IList should be changed after initialization, depending on user-input by two functions.

1. RepeatExercises: This function is called after a button press and repeats certain videos a specified number of times. It is necessary because several videos must be repeated. I want to do this by using a playlist, not by looping the video.
2. ModifyUrl: This function is called after a button press and should change only the videos with a true two-sided attribute. The variable currentUrl should be set for the first video to Url1 (when sidePlayNext == "left") and for the second same video to Url2 (when sidePlayNext == "right).

I've simplified the code as much as possible.

```
 @page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime theJavaScriptEngine;

<!-- Buttons for interaction -->
<button @onclick="StartVideo">Start video</button>
<button @onclick="RepeatExcercises">Repeat Excercises</button>
<button @onclick="ModifyUrl"> Modify Url (of Two Sided Videos)</button>

<!-- Video Element -->
 <div class="align-content-center">
    <video id="videoTagId" autoplay width="1080" height="720"  @onended="NextVideo">
        <source id="videoSourceId" src="@Videos[selected_video_id].CurrentUrl" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>

<!-- Developer output -->
@foreach(var v in Videos)
{   
     <li><code>Name: </code>@v.Name</li>
     <li><code>Video Current URl</code>@v.CurrentUrl</li>
     <li><code>Video URl 1</code>@v.Url1</li>
    <li><code>Video URL 2</code>@v.Url2</li>
    <li><code>Two Sided</code>@v.TwoSided</li>
    <li>...</li>
}

@code
{
    public int selected_video_id { get; set; } = 0;
    public IList<ExcerciseVideo>? Videos; // The list we use to store the Videos
    public int Repetitions { get; set; } = 2; // we want each exercise two times
    public string sidePlayNext {get; set; } = "left"; 

    public class ExcerciseVideo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CurrentUrl { get; set; }
        public string Url1 { get; set; } 
        public string Url2{ get; set; } // right hand side of each excercise
        public bool TwoSided { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Videos = new List<ExcerciseVideo>()
            {
                   new ExcerciseVideo {   
                                Name="Excercise A",
                                CurrentUrl = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4",
                                Url1="https://backtrainingapp.blob.core.windows.net/backtrainingvideos/20220220_184806[1].mp4",
                                Url2="https://backtrainingapp.blob.core.windows.net/backtrainingvideos/20220220_184806[1].mp4",
                                TwoSided=false},
                  new ExcerciseVideo {   
                                Name="Excercise B",
                                CurrentUrl = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4",
                                Url1="https://backtrainingapp.blob.core.windows.net/backtrainingvideos/20220220_184632[1].mp4",
                                Url2="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4",
                                TwoSided=true}

            };

    }

    public void RepeatExcercises()
    {
        // obtain values of the Video List
        int old_video_count = Videos.Count;
        int my_index = 0; 

        // Create a copy of the Video List
        IList<ExcerciseVideo> originalVideos = new List<ExcerciseVideo>(Videos);
        Videos.Clear(); // Clear the list --> we need a clean list for item insertion (in order to not have old items included) 

        // we loop over the list to repeat Videos
        // and insert them
        for (int l = 0; l < old_video_count; l++)
        {
            for (int repeats = 0; repeats < Repetitions; repeats++)
            {
                Videos.Insert(my_index, originalVideos[l]);
                my_index++; // increment the index
            }
        }
        
        StateHasChanged(); // Make sure that the changes are updated             
    }

    // Modify the Url of twoSided Videos
    public void ModifyUrl()
    {

        for (int m = 0; m < Videos.Count; m++)
        {                    
            // check whether a video is twosided
            if (Videos[m].TwoSided == true)
            {

                // check whether left side should be played
                // set Url1 in this case as value
                if (sidePlayNext == "left")
                {
                    Videos[m].CurrentUrl = Videos[m].Url1;
                    Console.WriteLine(sidePlayNext);
                    Console.WriteLine(Videos[m].CurrentUrl);
                    sidePlayNext = "right";
                }

                // check whether right side should be played
                // set Url2 in this case as value
                else if (sidePlayNext == "right")
                {
                    Videos[m].CurrentUrl = Videos[m].Url2;
                    Console.WriteLine(sidePlayNext);
                    Console.WriteLine(Videos[m].CurrentUrl);
                    sidePlayNext = "left";
                }

            }

            // All other cases in which no two sided videos are present
            // --> Current URl should correspond to Url1
            else if (Videos[m].TwoSided == false)
            {
                Videos[m].CurrentUrl = Videos[m].Url1;
                Console.WriteLine("No Direction");
                Console.WriteLine(Videos[m].CurrentUrl);
            }
        }

        StateHasChanged();          
    }

    protected void StartVideo()
    {
        selected_video_id = 0;
        theJavaScriptEngine.InvokeVoidAsync("loadVideo");
    }

    protected void NextVideo()
    {
        selected_video_id = selected_video_id  + 1;
        theJavaScriptEngine.InvokeVoidAsync("loadVideo");
    }

}
```

Testing and issues encountered (please also see the blazor fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/3ltiwlv3 ):

- Please check for testing the output below the video --> The list when the video loads seems to be populated correctly
- Then press the button "Repeat Excercises" --> The videos appear to be repeated as intended in the output below the video
- Then press the button "Modify Url" --> Look at Excercise B. **Unfortunately, the currentUrl of the first and second "Excercise B" are equal. The list in the second entry of Excercise B does not update to the value in Url2.**

I've tested the functions "RepeatExcercises" and "ModifyUrl" in Console apps and they work well there and update the list "Videos" as intended. **Ultimately, I would also like to update the src attribute of the VideoPlayer.** I've tried it with blazor bindings, but have also read that resetting sources of videos is difficult when already loaded (especially of a Url which on a specified index of a list...) - how could I do this?

```
<!-- Video Element -->
 <div class="align-content-center">
    <video id="videoTagId" autoplay width="1080" height="720"  @onended="NextVideo">
        <source id="videoSourceId" src="@Videos[selected_video_id].CurrentUrl" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

I've read up on all similar questions I could find online but am completely stuck now. I would greatly appreciate help.

Best regards & thank you
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazor is just working fine.

## Q1: updating url

The problem is with your code. When you press 'Repeat Exercises' you are inserting for twice the `ExcerciseVideo` `Excercise B`. Notice that do you have only one instance of `Excercise B` inserted for twice in the list (same instance object two times in the list).

When you iterate over the list, you found `Excercise B` for twice:

```
  A
  A
  B
  B  <--- // Is the same ExcerciseVideo instance as previous
```

Then, on first B you change url to some value and, on second B (that is the same B as before) you change back the url.

To fix your typo, just change function to:

```
public void RepeatExcercises()
{
    // obtain values of the Video List
    int old_video_count = Videos.Count;
    int my_index = 0; 

    // Create a copy of the Video List
    IList<ExcerciseVideo> originalVideos = new List<ExcerciseVideo>(Videos);
    Videos.Clear(); // Clear the list 

    // we loop over the list to repeat Videos
    // and insert them
    for (int l = 0; l < old_video_count; l++)
    {
        for (int repeats = 0; repeats < Repetitions; repeats++)
        {

            var new_video =  new ExcerciseVideo {   // <-- Important part
                            Name=originalVideos[l].Name,
                            CurrentUrl = originalVideos[l].CurrentUrl,
                            Url1=originalVideos[l].Url1,
                            Url2=originalVideos[l].Url2,
                            TwoSided=originalVideos[l].TwoSided};

            Videos.Insert(my_index, new_video);
            my_index++; // increment the index
        }
    }
    
    StateHasChanged(); // Make sure that the changes are updated             
}
```

## Q2: update video src

About second part of your question, update src attribute, is full explained at:

[C# StateHasChanged() in a razor component does not force  tag to load/change the mp4 playing, only using javascript seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57887668/842935)

Comment: Hello dani herrera, you are correct question 1 is resolved. Thank you very much for your help and support, it runs well now. I had a deep misconception about updating list items in C#/Blazor. I will read up on it, this is so important, I really don't want to get it wrong again. I will try to resolve Question 2 with the support of the post you mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Here, explained how to [say thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269683/842935) 