# Why is EventArgs e empty when using @volumechange event in Blazor MAUI video tag?

Tags: blazor, html5-video, maui, eventargs

I receive empty EventArgs if i use the @onvolumechange event in a .NET Blazor MAUI app on windows.

Player in Razor file:

```
<video @onvolumechange="@(e => PlayerVolumeChanged(e))" class="video" controls disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload nofullscreen noremoteplayback noplaybackrate" autoplay onloadstart="this.volume=@_videoPlayerVolume" onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();">
    <source src="@video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Logic in C# file:
`private void PlayerVolumeChanged(EventArgs e) { // e is empty here... }`

I am looking for a non-JavaScript solution to store the current volume of the player. The requirement is that the video player plays the video at the same volume every time. I expected the volume is stored in EventArgs e. But e is empty.
[Debug session in Visual Studio 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JaVo.png)

Comment: You should use the JavaScript to control the volume and the C# code cannot get the value and control the video. Here is the [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879294/c-sharp-statehaschanged-in-a-razor-component-does-not-force-video-tag-to-loa?rq=2) you can refer to.